# How to consume the complex json nested properties

Tags: javascript, angular

here i have a dynamic json

```
data = {
  "name": "deltha",
  "type": "object",

  "important": [
    "name",
    "id",
    "number"
  ],

  "information": {
    "place": {
      "editable": false,
      "visible": true
    },
    "info": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "visible": true

        }
      }
    },
    "Image": {
      "required": [
        "name"
      ],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "deltha": {
          "search": "yes"
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

here i am trying to check whether each and every nested property has "required" attribute or not

for ex

```
data['information']["Image"]
```

here from the above object i have a attribute i have "required" and under that "name" is there 
suppose like image how can i check each and every property to check there is 'required' if required there then how can i read that value dynamically

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the code you have written to try and solve your problem so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest to use a recursive function, here is a working example :  [stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snucnm](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snucnm)

Comment: Displaying undefined

Comment: my bad its working  i will my post could u check once https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpsmed

Comment: One small doubt how can i know which required property related to which one ?

Comment: If I understand well what you're asking for, then you only have to get the parent 'key' of the property

Answer (score 1):

use the `hasOwnProperty` check the property exist or not

```
let obj = data['information']["Image"];

if(obj.hasOwnProperty('required')){
   console.log(obj.required)
}
```

Comment: i can use that but   data['information']["Image"]; in this image will be not there for each and every attribute  it may be of some other name also instead of mentioning image dynamically is there any possibility for checking all the attibutes

Comment: Then you need to check whatever the attribute name exist on the parent before going inside that object

Comment: i already posted sample json could u just show me how to process it

Comment: you only posted one with image attribute only, how would i know the other attribute names

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpsmed  please check this url this image i am able to get but i unable get the required attribute and its value

Answer (score 1):

you can check the availability of the property as follows,

```
if (data.information.Image.required !== undefined) {
   console.log('prop is defined')
}
```